# Trying to set up a virtual environment with Python as directed from Learn Python the Hard Way

Tags: python-3.x

In the course Learn Python the Hard Way Exercise 46, you create a virtual environment by:

1. Installing vitualenv
2. making a directory for .venvs
3. creating a directory called lpthw then projects and a sub-dir called skeleton
4. adding a structure to the skeleton directory.
   ex. lpthw - projects - skeleton - NAME, bin, setup.py, tests, and docs
5. Then you activate the virtual environment and install the nose module
6. Then you run nose tests.

When I run $nosetests from my virtual environment on powershell from the skeleton directory, I get the attribute error:

```
if isinstance(tests, collections.Callable) and not is_suite:
```

AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'

I have tried changing the references of collections.Callable to collections.abc.callable in the relevant file, when I do this, nose returns a result of 0 tests. There should be at least 1.

The setup file is as follows.

setup.py:

```
 try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'description': 'My Project',
    'author': 'William Smith',
    'url': 'URL to go get it at.',
    'download_url': 'Where to download it.',
    'author_email': 'davwilsm1998@yahoo.com',
    'version': '0.1',
    'install_requires': ['nose'],
    'packages': ['NAME'],
    'scripts': [],
    'name': 'projectname'
}

setup(**config)
```

I find my problems are two-fold:
1. My $nosetests is using the Lib folder from my main Python installation where it should be using the Virtual Environment's Lib folder.
2. My $nosetests is either returning an attribute error or it is not actually running the test in the proper directory if it all.

How do I either make this work, or uninstall this and try a different method to create a virtual environment?

Comment: Perhaps you should show us your test setup code.  `collections.abc.Callable` is the correct name.

Comment: Added to original post. Also I have tried to change that in the nose/suite.py file but when I run $nosetest I get 0 tests when there should be at least 1.

Comment: Is there a question hidden here somewhere? I don't see one. I also don't see a problem description. I see a list of steps that need to be taken and a dump of some content formatted as code.

Comment: Okay sorry, first time making a post on here. Will correct.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem when running nosetests.
I looked it up and as the error was in a file suite.py
I had to replace occurrences of collections.Callable to collections.abc.Callable inside the file.
The location of the file will be inside the .venvs folder.
.venvs/lpthw/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nose/suite.py
The tests ran after that.